# Choose a random month from the past 2 years in Python

Tags: python, random

I would like to choose a random month between the current year and 2016.
This is my current, **very** naive, solution

```
from random import choice
def get_month():
    return choice({'2018-06','2018-05','2018-04','2018-03'})
```

It's obvious that this set will get too large in the future so what would be a better way of achieving this?

Comment: In what sense do you require randomness? February is shorter than March. Should February have `~28.25/365.25` probability of being chosen? Or should each month be given a `1/12` chance of being chosen? What about the current month? Should this month have a `16/365.25` probability of being chosen?

Comment: Each month should have 1/12 chance of being chosen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be you can have two list of month and year since, these will be fixed. Then, you can randomly choose between each and make a date to return. That way I think then no need to generate all different dates and no need to store in large list:

```
from random import choice
def get_month():
    months = list(range(1, 13)) # 12 months list
    year = list(range(2016, 2019)) # years list here
    val = '{}-{:02d}'.format(choice(year), choice(months))
    return val

get_month()
```

Result:

```
'2017-05'
```

## Update

Just in case if there is limitation on not exceeding current month if the year selected is current year then, you may need `if` condition for generating list of months as below:

```
from random import choice
from datetime import datetime

def get_month():

    today = datetime.today() # get current date
    year = list(range(2016, today.year+1)) # list till current date year

    # randomly select year and create list of month based on year
    random_year = choice(year)

    # if current year then do not exceed than current month
    if random_year == today.year:
        months = list(range(1, today.month+1))
    else:
        # if year is not current year then it is less so can create 12 months list
        months = list(range(1, 13)) 

    val = '{}-{:02d}'.format(random_year, choice(months))

    return val
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist I thought it would not exceed current month and current year. Is there something wrong?

Comment: *Some months are bigger than others. Some years' months are bigger than other years' months.*

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I am not quite sure I understand and I may be missing point on random selection. But does it mean number of days in months? I thought it would have 12 months if year is past or else till current month.

Comment: It depends on what distribution OP really is looking for here. (For what purpose/application?) My point was that for proper uniformity in date, February should have (on average) a `~28.25/365.25` chance of being chosen. This percentage depends on the year (among possibly other factors).

Comment: The months elapsed in the current year should have a higher probability of being selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the library `pandas` and use [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html)

```
choice(pd.date_range(start="2016-01-01", end="2018-01-01", freq='M'))
```

If you want it until today, you can just substitute the `start`and `end` arguments for whatever suitable, e.g.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
today = datetime.today()
two_years_ago = today - relativedelta(years=2)
choice(pd.date_range(start=two_years_ago, end=today, freq='M'))
```

Comment: Would "today - relativedelta(years=2)" include Jan. 2016 or just the last 24months? Do you think it would be better to hardcode the start date and avoid importing relativedelta?

Comment: It depends on your intentions. If you really want *always* from jan 2016 til today, I think you can hardcode that. If you always want an exact 2-year time frame, then relative delta is recommended :)

Answer (score 2):

I wish my code will give you some inspiration.

```
 import random
 import datetime

 def RandomMonth(st_year, st_month, ed_year, ed_month):
     """st_year, st_month and ed_year/month is int. """
     start_date = datetime.datetime(st_year, st_month, 1)
     end_date = datetime.datetime(ed_year, ed_month, 31)
     d_days = (end_date - start_date).days
     r_days = random.randint(0, ttl_days)
     r_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days = r_days)
     return r_date.strftime("%B/%Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

You've identified the issue correctly. While the set of discrete items can get unwieldy pretty quickly (actually it won't), selecting a [random integer over an arbitrary range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) is easy.

You should be able to compute the number of months between your dates of interest easily. That means that you have a trivial 1-to-1 mapping from months to integers. Now you can do

```
m = random.randrange(N)
```

where `N` is your total number of months (number of current month + 12 * number of whole years). Mapping back to months is easy using Python's [`datetime` API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```
origin = datetime.date(2016, 1, 1)
today = datetime.today()
n = (today.year - origin.year) * 12 + today.month - origin.month

m = random.randrange(n)
x = origin.replace(year=origin.year + m // 12, month=origin.month + m % 12)
```

Month delta (`n`) based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4040338/2988730) and month increment (`x`) based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2249988/2988730). Both computations will become slightly more complicated if you move away from January for the origin.

Answer (score 1):

just pick a random 1-24
then apply some date arithmetic to land on your month from the current date.

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from random import randint

refdate = date.today() #datetime.now() works too!
for i in range(0,10):
    #this will take off at least 1 month and 24 will return 2016-06 from 2018-06
    months = randint(1,24)  
    back = refdate - relativedelta(months=months)
    print ("start:%s - %02d months => %s" % (refdate, months, back))
```

output:

```
start:2018-06-17 - 24 months => 2016-06-17
start:2018-06-17 - 22 months => 2016-08-17
start:2018-06-17 - 21 months => 2016-09-17
start:2018-06-17 - 08 months => 2017-10-17
start:2018-06-17 - 16 months => 2017-02-17
start:2018-06-17 - 06 months => 2017-12-17
start:2018-06-17 - 07 months => 2017-11-17
start:2018-06-17 - 14 months => 2017-04-17
start:2018-06-17 - 07 months => 2017-11-17
start:2018-06-17 - 07 months => 2017-11-17
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do them seperately like take random year and take random month, then put it together

```
def get_month():
    year = random.choice([2016, 2017, 2018])
    month = random.choice(range(1,13))
    new_date = str(year) + "-" + str(month)
    return new_date
```

Comment: That's not uniform since current year doesn't have all the months.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `calendar`:

```
from random import choice
import calendar
def get_month():
    l = []
    y = 0
    for i in range(2016,2019):
        l.append(str(i)+'-'+str(calendar.monthrange(i,12)[0]))
    return choice(l)
print(get_month())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I came with a lighter solution than the one using pandas

```
current_month = datetime.today().month
current_year = datetime.today().year 
start_year = 2016

#total months between now and the start year
total_months = current_month + (current_year - start_year)*12 

months = []
month_count = 1
year_count = start_year

#iterate through the list, when it reaches 13, increment year_count and reset the month_count to 1
for month in range(total_months):
    if month_count<13:
        months.append(str(year_count) + "-" + str("{0:0=2d}".format(month_count)))
        month_count+=1
    if month_count == 13:
        year_count+=1
        month_count=1
```

results

```
['2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-03', '2016-04', '2016-05', '2016-06', '2016-07', '2016-08', '2016-09', '2016-10', '2016-11', '2016-12', '2017-01', '2017-02', '2017-03', '2017-04', '2017-05', '2017-06', '2017-07', '2017-08', '2017-09','2017-10', '2017-11', '2017-12', '2018-01', '2018-02', '2018-03', '2018-04', '2018-05', '2018-06']
```

for some reason, when I replace "if month_count == 13" with "else", it only goes up to 2018-04

I would appreciate some feedback on this solution.